# Vite+react fast app not rendering in browser

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZr3.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esjp6.jpg)
This error throw

Please help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3QA9.jpg) please
I trying to solve this but I don't find the problem please help everyone  plis help
My all task is done but its not working

I trying to solve this but I don't find the problem please help everyone  plis help

My all task is done but its not working